# Can I return `void` from a function with a type predicate?

Tags: typescript

When writing data validation APIs, I often provide two functions -- one that returns a `boolean` and one that throws. The one that throws usually has a `void` return type.

```js
interface MyType {
    numberField: number;
    stringField: string;
}

function isMyType(o: any): o is MyType {
    return typeof o === "object"
        && o !== null
        && typeof o.numberField === "number"
        && typeof o.stringField === "string";
}

function validateMyType(o: any): void {
    if (!isMyType(o)) {
        throw new Error("Invalid MyType object.")
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is use a type predicate so that all subsequent code in the same block (or any sub-block) can assume the type of the object.

```js
const input: any = ...;
validateMyType(input);
// here I would like TypeScript to understand that input is a MyType
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the new assertion functions in TypeScript 3.7. Read more about them [in the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

For your example, you would change the return type of the `validate` function to `asserts o is MyType`. This informs the type system about the type of the parameter in subsequent code in the same scope after a `validate` call.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the new [custom type assertion syntax](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695)

```
interface MyType {

  numberField: number;

  stringField: string;
}
function isValid(o: any): o is MyType {
  return typeof o === "object"
    && o !== null
    && typeof o.numberField === "number"
    && typeof o.stringField === "string";
}

function validate(o: any): asserts o is MyType{
  if (!isValid(o)) {
    throw new Error("Invalid MyType object.")
  }
}

declare var o: any;
validate(o)
o.numberField //ok
o.numberField2 //err
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8Aq6AOKDeAUIcsiAK4C2ARtAGLAQA2AJgFxlW1QDcxpAZzBRQAcwbN2yISJCi+AX0IxyIBGGAB7EMmACAanCbAWACk0c4IdAEoOm3QLRZcBEsigQw5KDrCvNGGQHAF4w5AAiTWoAKwh1CPdSADJk4OQAQnCKJiYk5FTkfzxA4IA6Chp6RlZkMJDIyu5E0hS04ohSzTKZMQla+sjeuQjFYhU1DW1kADcjEzhIc0trO2Q4AQFoMCcHPWdsPCJSYCDTDL1DYzNNGxtkY9awAAsoTQB3MghPgFEoN6gpgiAEkQHNrgdXMFYvEwGUIjZ3EolIQWPEmHBPLNMcEVug+OCFktboRuk1qpJkAB6KmaADWpIqXAprAATNSqdAoEA)